# Postgresql basic performance on queries

Tags: postgresql

What should be the keyword to google for to get better performance on queries where im currently doing double the work.

```
select ... 
where trim(leading '0' from fieldA) = trim(leading '0' from fieldB)
and char_length(trim(leading '0' from fieldA)) > 10
```

As seen above I'm currently trimming fieldA twice

Thanks for the answers!

Edit:

Main question here is how to do something like following in postgresql or is it even doable?

```
select ... 
??trimmed_fieldA = trim(leading '0' from fieldA)??
...
where trimmed_fieldA = trim(leading '0' from fieldB)
and char_length(trimmed_fieldA) > 10
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: `trim(leading '0' from fieldA)` sounds suspiciously as if you are storing number in a `text` column. If that is true, storing the values in a proper `integer` (or `bigint`) column would be better

Comment: The actual performance impact of calling `trim()` twice on the same column should matter that match. But applying a function on a column will make it impossible for the optimizer to use an index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the comments.

Changing the column to integer is something to aim for.
I'm editing the question for better explaining what I was after first place.